# Permanently add GitLab personal access token

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IDEA 2021.2, paid plan. How can I add a GitLab (self-hosted) personal access token to IDEA so all repos I clone etc from this server work without requesting token or needing me to add into URL?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regrettably, there is no option to keep a token and use it for every repository, so you will need to supply it everytime you clone a new repository.

But if you have "Use credential helper" enabled under Preferences | Version Control | Git then the rest operations should work fine

**EDIT**
'Use credential helper' will allow you to store credentials for gitlab.com in your system credential manager (Keychain, Windows Credentials manager) for your account, so first clone will ask you for credentials, but clones for the same account shouldn't ask for a password again

But there is no GitLab integration for now, please feel free to vote:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109294